# Exclude specific libraries for source-stepping through SourceLink while debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, f#, visual-studio-2022, sourcelink

I really like the new features of recent Visual Studio 2022 versions that allow source-stepping through GitHub-hosted content that's commit-hash specific.

However, occasionally I prefer not to do this. For instance, I typically do not need to source-step through `FSharp.Core` and being able to disable it would improve my debugging experience (while keeping it for all other libs).

I am wondering if there's some way to disable SourceLink for specific libraries or groups of libraries, similar to how that can be done with exclude/include lists for loading symbols?

I.e., like the following, but then for SourceLink?

[image]